# Objective-C: How to communicate between classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

after an research i discovered the sigleton that may help me but i have some problem to understand how it work.
i need that 2 class comunicate each other, here an example:
i have a tableView wich field are dinamic.
this is my code on viewController.h file:

```
    -(void)ottieniMarche{

    responseSimulate = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"pollo",@"cane",@"gatto",@"verme",@"gallo",@"topo",@"canguro",@"elefante",@"giraffa" ,nil];

}
```

Now i have to send this information on my mainTableView.m ad the code that i'm actually using is this:

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        elementMainTableView = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",@"eee",@"fff",@"ggg",@"hhh",@"iii" ,nil];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Now i have to change the elementMainTableView value with the responseSimulate value. I mean that the content of my maintableView are the same of my responseSimulate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to refresh the content of the `UITableView` based on model changes.

`UITableView` requires a class that conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to provide its row and section data.  Often, that's a `UITableViewController`, but it does not have to be.  The data source for your `UITableView` could the other class to which you refer.  In that case, the key is to ask the reload the data, i.e. `[tableView reloadData]` when you change the data.

In your case, if your `MainTableView` (I'm inferring this is actually a `UITableViewController` subclass...) conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, then you could solve the problem using Key-Value Observing for example:  (**Note**, this example assumes you are using ARC.)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    elementMainTableView = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"elementMainTableView" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
{
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"elementMainTableview"] )
    {
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
}
```

This assumes that you expose `elementMainTableView` as a property on `MainTableView`.

Now, in the other class (?ViewController) your method:

```
-(void)ottieniMarche {
    responseStimulate = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pollo",@"cane",@"gato",nil];
    _mainTableViewController.elementMainTableView = responseStimulate;
}
```

For this to work, you will need your `ViewController` to keep a reference to the `MainTableView`, e.g. `_mainTableViewController` above.